# How to modify bouncy castle framework jars?

Tags: android, android-framework

I have implemented bouncycastle functionality in my android app. Now i want to remove bouncy castle folder from my application and use bouncy castle framwork jar provided by android. so need to change bouncy castle jars according to my application and use it , How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

> and use bouncy castle framwork jar provided by android

That is not part of the Android SDK. In fact, Bouncy Castle may be removed entirely in the future, as Android has switched to a different `javax.crypto` SPI.

Android developers wishing to use Bouncy Castle classes should be using the [Spongy Castle JAR](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/).